# How can I guarantee to get latest data when I use Coroutine in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A is from the project architecture-samples, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/DefaultTasksRepository.kt).

The `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()` is suspend function, so it maybe run asynchronously.

When I call the function `getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean)` with the paramter `True`, I'm afraid that `return tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()` will be fired before `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()`.

I don't know if the Code B can guarantee `return tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()` will be fired after `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()`.

**Code A**

```
class DefaultTasksRepository(
    private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksRepository {

   override suspend fun getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean): Result<List<Task>> {
        // Set app as busy while this function executes.
        wrapEspressoIdlingResource {

            if (forceUpdate) {
                try {
                    updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    return Result.Error(ex)
                }
            }
            return tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()
        }
   }

   private suspend fun updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource() {
        val remoteTasks = tasksRemoteDataSource.getTasks()

        if (remoteTasks is Success) {
            // Real apps might want to do a proper sync, deleting, modifying or adding each task.
            tasksLocalDataSource.deleteAllTasks()
            remoteTasks.data.forEach { task ->
                tasksLocalDataSource.saveTask(task)
            }
        } else if (remoteTasks is Result.Error) {
            throw remoteTasks.exception
        }
    }
   ...

}
```

**Code B**

```
class DefaultTasksRepository(
    private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksRepository {

    override suspend fun getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean): Result<List<Task>> {
        // Set app as busy while this function executes.
        wrapEspressoIdlingResource {
            coroutineScope {
                if (forceUpdate) {
                    try {
                        updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        return Result.Error(ex)
                    }
                }
            }
            return tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()
        }
    }

    ...    

}
```

**Added Content**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

If somebody implement `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()` with `lauch` just like Code C, are you sure the Code C is `return tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()` will be fired after `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()` when I call the function `getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean)` with the paramter `True`?

**Code C**

```
 class DefaultTasksRepository(
        private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
        private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
        private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
    ) : TasksRepository {

       override suspend fun getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean): Result<List<Task>> {
            // Set app as busy while this function executes.
            wrapEspressoIdlingResource {

                if (forceUpdate) {
                    try {
                        updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        return Result.Error(ex)
                    }
                }
                return tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()
            }
       }

      private suspend fun updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource() {
            val remoteTasks = tasksRemoteDataSource.getTasks()

            if (remoteTasks is Success) {
                // Real apps might want to do a proper sync, deleting, modifying or adding each task.
                tasksLocalDataSource.deleteAllTasks()
                launch {                                          //I suppose that launch can be fired
                    remoteTasks.data.forEach { task ->
                        tasksLocalDataSource.saveTask(task)
                    }
                }

            } else if (remoteTasks is Result.Error) {
                throw remoteTasks.exception
            }
        }
   }
```

**New Added Content**

To Joffrey: Thanks!

I think that the Code D can be compiled.

In this case, when `forceUpdate` is true, `tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()` maybe be run before `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()` is done.

**Code D**

```
class DefaultTasksRepository(
    private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
    private val myCoroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) : TasksRepository {

    override suspend fun getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean): Result<List<Task>> {
        // Set app as busy while this function executes.
        wrapEspressoIdlingResource {

            if (forceUpdate) {
                try {
                    updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource(myCoroutineScope)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    return Result.Error(ex)
                }
            }
            return tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource(myCoroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {
        val remoteTasks = tasksRemoteDataSource.getTasks()

        if (remoteTasks is Success) {
            // Real apps might want to do a proper sync, deleting, modifying or adding each task.
            tasksLocalDataSource.deleteAllTasks()
            myCoroutineScope.launch {
                remoteTasks.data.forEach { task ->
                    tasksLocalDataSource.saveTask(task)
                }
            }

        } else if (remoteTasks is Result.Error) {
            throw remoteTasks.exception
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: i think you don't understand how coroutines works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTDXo0-SKuU

Comment: They will run sequentially. That's the main point of coroutines. Instead of callbacks, you write sequential code.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Not sure I understand your follow-up question. You're asking if it still holds true that the code is sequential even if the suspend function you're calling launches other coroutines? If so, the answer is yes. The coroutine function that called this suspend function will not continue until the suspend function returns, no matter what. The code within the launched coroutine inside your suspend function probably won't be finished running by this time unless you `.join()` it in your suspend function.

Comment: Thanks!

 1:  In any case, the coroutine function that called the other suspend function will not continue until the other suspend function returns, right?

 2:  Why do I need to add  `.join()` in `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()` in Code C ?, If the item 1 is correct, the coroutine function that called the other suspend function will always wait until the other suspend function returns.

Comment: @HelloCW in code in C it may happen getTasks() is called before setTasks() because launch schedules a new launch of the coroutine, if the dispatcher is single-threaded it will be called after getTasks(), if dispatcher is multi-threaded, then its no guarentee which one called first. Other than that Code A and B will guarantee sequential execution get will called after the function completes.

Comment: @HelloCW please check my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`suspend` functions look like regular functions from the call site's point of view because they execute sequentially just like regular synchronous functions.
What I mean by this is that the instructions following a plain call to a `suspend` function do not execute until the called function completes its execution.

This means that code A is fine (when `forceUpdate` is true, `tasksLocalDataSource.getTasks()` will never run before `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource()` is done), and the `coroutineScope` in code B is unnecessary.

Now regarding code C, structured concurrency is here to save you.
People simply cannot call `launch` without a `CoroutineScope` receiver.
Since `TaskRepository` doesn't extend `CoroutineScope`, the code C as-is will not compile.

There are 2 ways to make this compile though:

1. Using `GlobalScope.launch {}`: this will cause the problem you expect, indeed. The body of such a `launch` will be run asynchronously and independently of the caller. `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource` can in this case return before the `launch`'s body is done. The only way to control this is to use `.join()` on the `Job` returned by the call to `launch` (which waits until it's done). This is why it is usually not recommended to use the `GlobalScope`, because it can "leak" coroutines.
2. wrapping calls to `launch` in a `coroutineScope {...}` inside `updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource`. This will ensure that all coroutines launched within the `coroutineScope` block are actually finished before the `coroutineScope` call completes. Note that everything that's *inside* the `coroutineScope` block may very well run concurrently, though, depending on how `launch`/`async` are used, but this is the whole point of using `launch` in the first place, isn't it?

Now with Code D, my answer for code C sort of still holds. Whether you pass a scope or use the `GlobalScope`, you're effectively creating coroutines with a bigger lifecycle than the suspending function that starts them.
Therefore, it does create the problem you fear.
But why would you pass a `CoroutineScope` if you don't want implementers to launch long lived coroutines in the provided scope?

Assuming you don't do that, it's unlikely that a developer would use the `GlobalScope` (or any scope) to do this. It's generally bad style to create long-lived coroutines from a suspending function. If your function is suspending, callers usually expect that when it completes, it has actually done its work.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my new added content in the question?

Comment: I edited my answer in an attempt to answer your added content